# Image in cardview not filling it completely

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this cardview with an image but the thing is, the image does not fill the card and I am not sure why this is happening (changing the width does not seem to affect anything).

This is how it looks:
[image]

This is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
   android:orientation="vertical">

   <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
       android:layout_width="180dp"
       android:layout_height="130dp"
       app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
       app:strokeColor="@color/white">

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/iv_news"
           android:layout_width="250dp"
           android:layout_height="130dp"
           android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
           android:background="@drawable/card_background_shape"
           android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
   </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tv_title"
       android:layout_width="180dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:text="@string/news_title"
       android:textAlignment="center"
       android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
       android:textColor="@color/black" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `android:layout_marginStart="10dp"` in your `ImageView`.

It only should look like this:

```
<ImageView
           android:id="@+id/iv_news"
           android:layout_width="250dp"
           android:layout_height="130dp"
           android:background="@drawable/card_background_shape"
           android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

set your cardView android:layout_width="wrap_content" or "250dp"

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="130dp"
   app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
   app:strokeColor="@color/white">

   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/iv_news"
       android:layout_width="250dp"
       android:layout_height="130dp"
       android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
       android:background="@drawable/card_background_shape"
       android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

  </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```